# Where to learn android programming?

Tags: android

I already know the basics of Java but where should you go to learn android app development. I want to learn how to make pro apps and one day make a 3D game. Where do/did you go to learn android development? And please don't say university.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start using the official resources:

- https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

2 Great books from Pragmatic Bookshelf:

- [Hello, Android 4th Edition](https://pragprog.com/book/eband4/hello-android)
- [Rapid Android Development](https://pragprog.com/book/dsproc/rapid-android-development)

Other Books:

- [Programming Android](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449389694)
- [Beginning Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428)

Google should be your best friend.

Comment: The official docs suck, I am saying this after they gave me 400 lines of code for handling the camera with no explanation. The official docs are not for beginners, they are for programmers with half a decade of Java experience, the same thing is stated there.

Answer (score 0):

[www.teamtreehouse.com](http://www.teamtreehouse.com) is a good place for beginners in my opinion :)

give it a shot :D

Answer (score 0):

[It can help you for android development in the beginning.][1]

http://www.androidhive.info/